# Serializing NotificationQuerySet from django-notifications-hq not working

Tags: python, django, serialization, notifications, django-rest-framework

So, i'm trying to add to my API made with DRF (Django REST Framework) the notifications Model, but i'm getting this error:

`AttributeError: 'NotificationQuerySet' object has no attribute 'recipient'`

I'm trying to serialize a django app model, Notification. It's from this app:

https://github.com/django-notifications/django-notifications

My ViewSet class is this:

```
class NotificationsViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = NotificationsSerializer
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Notification.objects.all()
        return Response(NotificationsSerializer(queryset).data)
```

And here my serializer:

```
class NotificationsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Notification
        fields = ('recipient','description')
        depth = 0
```

So, when data pass to serializer, it becomes "Void" or without any data. 
Doing something like into the **list method**:

`print queryset[0]`  returns a Notification object normaly. But when passing this queryset to the serializer, seems to be null, and the AttributeError comes.

Also, tried this with the console:

`notifications = Notification.objects.all()`

That returns a **NotificationQuerySet** object (iterable). Then I can:

```
for noti in notifications:
    print noti
```

That would output all the **unicode** methods of every notification.
With every Notification instance, i can also access to Model propierties:

```
for noti in notifications:
    print noti.recipient
```

And works very well.

Why is not working when passing this to the serializer? Its weird...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `many=True` when initializing a serializer with a queryset. DRF will assume you are passing a single object and try to get the fields directly from it if you do not tell it that you are passing in multiple objects.

Comment: God... thanks for the answer. I was blind about this... Hours spent with this, and I still have some views with that parameter. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 1):

Heres a full implementation where the readme leaves off for drf

urls.py

```
...
import notifications.urls

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("inbox/notifications/", views.NotificationViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='notifications'),
]
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):                           
    class Meta:                                   
        model = get_user_model()

class NotificationSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    recipient = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    unread = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
    target = GenericNotificationRelatedField(read_only=True)
    verb = serializers.CharField()
```

views.py

```
from notifications.models import Notification
from .serializers import NotificationSerializer

NotificationViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = NotificationSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Notification.objects.all()
        return Response(NotificationSerializer(queryset, many=True).data)
```